# Jenkins git funny refname

Tags: android, git, jenkins

I'm trying to use the git publisher to publish some changes that Jenkins made back to my repo, but getting this weird error:

```
Pushing HEAD to branch master at repo Android
Opening connection
Counting objects
Finding sources
Writing objects
ERROR: Failed to push branch master to Android
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: funny refname
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.JGitAPIImpl$8.execute(JGitAPIImpl.java:1812)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitPublisher.perform(GitPublisher.java:342)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:761)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:721)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:670)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1776)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Build step 'Git Publisher' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

**Here are my settings:**

- repo name: Android
- Refspec: {empty -- nothing entered here}
- Branches to build: master
- Checout to specific local branch: master

**Git publisher:**

- Push only if build succeeds: true
- Merge results: true
- Force push: true
- Branch to push: master
- Target remote name: Android

Any ideas?

**Additional Info**
If I uncheck 'merge results', then it completes successfully, but my nothing is actually pushed to my master branch.

Answer (score 0):

The issue [[JENKINS-20393] Git plugin 2.0 JGit implementation does not publish merge result](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20393) that contains [a comment with a message like yours](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20393?focusedCommentId=231931&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-231931) has been resolved *"3 days ago".* I guess you're not using a version that new.

> #### *Description*
>
> *If I use the jgit implementation in a job which should merge from multiple branches, the merge result is not pushed back to origin. Merge result is pushed if I use the command line implementation in the same job.*